# MVC 5 - List view inside a view (Different models)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am creating my first MVC web application and have ran into a problem if anyone could help me out.

I have a model called "Client" which has all the columns for client information, I then have another model called "Job" which has job information.

Now Client has an "Public virtual ICollection jobs", while "Job" has "public virtual Client Client" - So a client can have many jobs, while a job can only have one client.

I have created a basic CRUD functionality for the client, and now with that in the "Details" page of a particular client - I want to display a table with all the jobs associated with that client. - So a CRUD within a CRUD (If that makes sense?) I tried creating a view of job lists and using "Html.RenderPartial" on the client details page - But with no luck.

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Excuse the inexperience with MVC! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the `Jobs` property on your `Client` class, you can iterate through that and display the jobs in your details view.

```
@model Client
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
<h3>Jobs for this client </h3>
@if(Model.Jobs!=null)
{
  <table>
    <tr>
       <th>Title </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var job in Model.Jobs)
    {
      <tr><td>@job.Title</td></tr>
    }
  </table>
}
else
{
  <p>No jobs found</p>
}
```

Assuming your Details action method returns a Client object.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  var client = new Client();
  //Hardcoding the values for demo. You may get it from db using the Id
  client.Name="Microsoft";
  client.Jobs= new List<Job>{
    new Job { Title ="Developer"},
    new Job { Title ="proDuct Manager"}
  };
  return View(client);
}
```

Comment: Managed to do it this way! Thank you so much! Your a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

To load job list for client you may use :
in client Vivew

```
@model Client

    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>

    @Html.Render("_jobpartialView",client.Jobs)
```

In "_jobpartialView"

```
@model IEnumerable<Jobs>

@foreach(var job in Model)
{
//your code
}
```